# jquery ie8 scrollTop and offset issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, offset, scrolltop

I am attempting to position a very simple hover tool tip directly above a series of elements on a page. My positioning code works perfectly in FF, but in IE8 the positioning fails if the page is scrolled. I am compensating for scroll, but in IE8 it seems I have to double the number for it to work correctly.

```
$('.evidence_thumb').mouseenter(function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    $top = ((position.top - $('#icon_tool_tip').height()) + $(window).scrollTop()) + 10;
    $left = ((position.left) + $(window).scrollLeft()) - 40;
    $('#icon_tool_tip').offset({ top: $top, left: $left });
});
```

The margin of error in display with the above code is always exactly the amount of the scrollTop. I haven't tested with horizontal scroll, but I assume it will have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this "solved" exactly, but I stopped using the jquery offset in favor of css.  I changed:
    $('#icon_tool_tip').offset({ top: $top, left: $left });
to:
    $('#icon_tool_tip').css({ top: $top, left: $left });

It made my issue go away, but there is something odd going on here with the offset that I would have liked to understand.

Comment: Did $top and $left have units when you used them with offset()? According to jQuery doc, it looks like you don't need units with offset()

Comment: They did not have units. Oddly neither does the css call which I thought would require them, though I didn't check docs to be sure.  If I ever get unswamped I plan to revisit this issue and find out what is going on.